# Windows file ownership and security with vb.net?

Tags: windows, vb.net, security, authentication, vb.net-2010

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

- On 1 PC there are 3 normal users and 2 administrators: a total of 5.
- I need the VB.net application the **running on admin 1** account to create a file and set ownership and permissions only available to admin 2 so that ***only admin 2*** is available to access, delete, etc. to that file.
- The admin 1 cannot access the file through Windows, but the application running on that user account can.
- So in meantime (while app is running on admin 1), if the file needs changes, the application should again be able to change the file.

**Note:** The application knows passwords and login information for both accounts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14476641/922198

Comment: I suggest you to use cacls command. Set owner permissions per file. You can run cacls command in your vb.net code easily with Process.Start

Comment: @VahidFarahmand do you have any examples on this?

Answer (score 1):

> The admin 1 cannot access the file through windows but the application running on that user account (admin 1) can.

You can't make this happen the way you seem to want. Programs running on admin 1 "are" that user. The user could always access the file via Windows if the program can.

You could make the program encrypt the data in the file.  The admin 1 user would be able to read the encrypted contents (seemingly random data), and change (thus destroying) it, or delete the file.  However, unless that user breaks the encryption, only the program (that knows how the file was encrypted) would be able to make valid changes to it.  The other user who needs to work with the file would need to access it through the program (or another one that could decrypt it for use).

Another alternative would be to make another user account, grant access to the files only to admin 2 and the new account, and have the application access it after "impersonating" that new account.  Then you'd deny access to the program itself for all users except admin 1.  However, even doing this, a "domain admin" could get at the file.

Keep in mind that any user working with the file contents via software would be able to (for example) print it or copy it to the clipboard, and do anything with it.  If you can't trust your employees to do the right thing, you're probably doomed anyway.

Comment: So how exactly i should block access to anyone except admin2 to the file? if i use *FileSystemSecurity* and *.AddAccessRule* i can set the security permissions for current loged in user to block access but how do i set it for other users? and how to set the ownership to the admin2?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried LogonUser and [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate.aspx)?

Comment: I didn't. Do you have any example on this?

Comment: Also it's one of the recipes in this (rather dated) cookbook http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programmer%2527s-Cookbook-Pro-Developer-Matthew-MacDonald/dp/073561931X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1358371489&sr=8-1

Comment: I dont understand i set the access rules to file deny from all users but again i can just go properties to file and again allow to myself?

Comment: Yes sorry my emphasis was on the program having its own account rather than on the fact that as J.Merrill and you both point out, a domain admin can always take ownership of the file. If your emphasis is on keeping the file contents well and truly secure under all circumstances then  encryption  of some sort is the best way forward, and that's already well covered by J.Merrill too.

Comment: Well thats what i am trying to do own account to program so only program can access file. but even if i do that a new account i can easily go to any admin 1 or 2 and change permissions of file to allow :(

Answer (score 0):

After passing a little time on MSDN this is all i could come up with, its the same thing as "Run as" provided by the windows

tested & working fine

Code :

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices


 Module Module1

    Public Infinite As System.UInt32 = Convert.ToUInt32(&HFFFFFFF)
    Public Startf_UseStdHandles As Int32 = &H100
    Public StdOutputHandle As Int32 = -11
    Public StdErrorHandle As Int32 = -12

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Public Structure StartupInfo
        Public cb As Integer
        Public reserved As String
        Public desktop As String
        Public title As String
        Public x As Integer
        Public y As Integer
        Public xSize As Integer
        Public ySize As Integer
        Public xCountChars As Integer
        Public yCountChars As Integer
        Public fillAttribute As Integer
        Public flags As Integer
        Public showWindow As UInt16
        Public reserved2 As UInt16
        Public reserved3 As Byte
        Public stdInput As IntPtr
        Public stdOutput As IntPtr
        Public stdError As IntPtr
    End Structure 'StartupInfo

    Friend Structure ProcessInformation
        Public process As IntPtr
        Public thread As IntPtr
        Public processId As Integer
        Public threadId As Integer
    End Structure 'ProcessInformation


    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Public Function CreateProcessWithLogonW(ByVal userName As String, ByVal domain As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal logonFlags As UInt32, ByVal applicationName As String, ByVal commandLine As String, ByVal creationFlags As UInt32, ByVal environment As UInt32, ByVal currentDirectory As String, ByRef startupInfo As StartupInfo, ByRef processInformation As ProcessInformation) As Boolean
    End Function


    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function GetExitCodeProcess(ByVal process As IntPtr, ByRef exitCode As UInt32) As Boolean
    End Function


    <DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function WaitForSingleObject(ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal milliseconds As UInt32) As UInt32
    End Function


    <DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function GetStdHandle(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function


    <DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function CloseHandle(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function


    <STAThread()> _
    Overloads Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
        Dim MyPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4)
        Marshal.WriteInt32(MyPointer, StdOutputHandle)
        Dim MyErrorPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4)
        Marshal.WriteInt32(MyErrorPointer, StdErrorHandle)
        Dim startupInfo As New StartupInfo
        startupInfo.reserved = Nothing
        startupInfo.flags = startupInfo.flags And Startf_UseStdHandles
        startupInfo.stdOutput = MyPointer  
        startupInfo.stdError = MyErrorPointer     

        Dim exitCode As System.UInt32 = Convert.ToUInt32(123456)
        Dim processInfo As New ProcessInformation

        Dim command As String = "c:\windows\Notepad.exe"
        Dim user As String = "administrator"
        Dim domain As String = System.Environment.MachineName
        Dim password As String = "admin acct password"
        Dim currentDirectory As String = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

        Try
            CreateProcessWithLogonW(user, domain, password, Convert.ToUInt32(1), _
                command, command, Convert.ToUInt32(0), Convert.ToUInt32(0), _
                currentDirectory, startupInfo, processInfo)
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString())
        End Try
        Console.WriteLine("Running ...")
        WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.process, Infinite)
        GetExitCodeProcess(processInfo.process, exitCode)

        Console.WriteLine("Exit code: {0}", exitCode)

        CloseHandle(processInfo.process)
        CloseHandle(processInfo.thread)
    End Sub 

End Module
```

Comment: So this would be a solution to change the locked file. Thanks. But how to lock the file as i explained.

Comment: The admin 1 cannot access the file through Windows, but the application running on that user account can. ? can elaborate? why cant admin access?

Comment: because no one should be able to change, read or delete the file except the admin 2, but application must work under admin 1 environment (so the program should be able to change, read or delete file). And the program knows both accounts passwords.